# Applying function to multiple .csv files

Tags: r

I have a files key (called "key") with two columns, like below:

| ID | newID |
| --- | --- |
| 801deoi | 1 |
| 802oieu | 2 |
| 803qpoe | 3 |
| 804intw | 4 |

These participants complete questions before and after a distraction task, and I have replaced their alphanumeric ID code (on the left) with a new participant number (on the right).

Their .csv file is currently named after their ID, and I want to rename their scores after the distraction task (.csv file) with their new ID code (newID above) and with "_a" to signify that this is their score after the distraction task.

```
files <- list.files(path = 'data/', pattern = '*.csv', full.names = TRUE) 

key <- read.csv("key.csv")

Map(function(x, y) {
  tmp <- read.csv(files[x])
  tmp$participant <- paste0(y, "_a")
  write.csv(tmp, paste0(y, "_a"), row.names = FALSE, na = "")
}, key$ID, key$newID)
```

I have tried the code above, however the following error appears: "Error in file(file, "rt"): invalid 'description' argument". Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried figuring out what line causes the error by commenting out parts of the function? It isn't clear to me if the error is a read or write error. Also, it would help if we knew the contents of `files`.

Comment: Unless you've added names to the `files` vector, `files[x]` isn't going to do anything. The index expects either an integer or a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid using `write.*` in a function that should return something. Instead, I would just use a for loop. I don't have your data, so I can't test this, but here's how I might do this:

```
key <- read.csv("key.csv", as.is = TRUE)

for (id in key$ID) {
  pat <- paste0("*", id, "*")
  f <- list.files(path = 'data/', pattern = pat, full.names = TRUE)
  tmp <- read.csv(f)
  
  new_id <- key[key$ID == id, 'newID']
  tmp$participant <- paste0(new_id, "_a")
  
  write.csv(tmp, paste0('data/', new_id, "_a.csv"), row.names = FALSE, na = "")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this didn't work as it just produced an overall .csv called "_a" without any of the ID numbers carried through

Comment: @abc_95, I fixed a typo in the answer (had `key$id` instead of `key$ID`) and set the output directory to data. I ran it with fake data and it's working here. Let me know if it works for you now or if I need more details.